# Test automation - Win32 app - White/UI automation - problem with recognizing objects

Tags: testing, automation, ui-automation, white-framework

I’m looking for alternative for existing tests written in QTP for my Win32 application written in Borland C++.
My candidate is White which based on UI Automation because it’s native solution, 
I can create my tests using .NET/C# and easily integrate it with nUnit and Hudson.

White
http://white.codeplex.com

MS UI Automation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx

UI Verify
http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com

I use UI Verify as a spy to identify properties of objects I want to find in my tests.
More or less when I can see something in the spy, I can find it using UI Automation/White.
Generally I don't have much problems with recognizing objects 
but when I try to search some content inside the tab contained in Tab Panel 
or try to see MenuItems of Menu bar then the problem appears.

UI Automation/UI Verify works wired. When I run UI Verify (1.0 version) I see that objects can be registered properly only then 
when I set 'Focus tracking' option and click on target objects or change the keyboard cursor on them. Otherwise it's impossible to find them. 
UI Verifier can show me children of my 'tab' panel then. But I can’t find them using UI Automation/White. This is example code:

Tab tab = window.Get();
ITabPage tabPage = tab.SelectedTab;
AutomationElementCollection newCol = tabPage.AutomationElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, Condition.TrueCondition);
window.Get("buttonName");

the collection is empty even though spy see the children.

1. Does any of you have some experience with White/UI Automation library that he/she would like to share with me?
2. I want to implement the tracking feature from the spy to my tests. Can you help me with that? I'm trying to study the code of UIA Verify spy. I think that there are two classes responsible for catching the objects: FocusChangeListener and FocusTracer - this is the code:

http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9992#214260
http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9992#214192

Requirements:
1. Windows SDK
2. .NET 3.5
3. White
4. UIA Verify code

1. Do you have any better alternative for White/UI Automation?

R.

Comment: what is the value of tabPage?  Is it null?  Have you tried White's TabItem control type instead of TabPage?

Comment: Hi I'm facing with the same problem - did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Could you, the R or YoYo, put your form compiled or in source codes (preferable without the internal logic) somewhere on a file share?
I've never seen a control that'd be not caught using UI Automation if UIAVerify sees it. I saw such windows, which could be only caught with the Focus Tracking feature of UIAVerify. This case, such a window is untouchable by UI Automation search.

Regarding a control, are you sure that the controls you struggling with have the Name property? Maybe, this is a value available only by means of ValuePattern, not the Name?

Comment: I don't have the access to the code right now, but it was Borland C++ and that was very paintfull. The objects that I was trying to discover were dynamic and that cause a big pain. At the end I used a hybrid solution using White/UI Automation and TestComplete (because my company has already bought the licenses). But if closed/commercial TestComplete could access these objects then for sure it's possible using open source tools.

Comment: You could try the UIAutomation PowerShell module or UIAutomationSpy (both are from uiautomation.codeplex.com). Some Deplhi (I think Borland C++ are of the same family) controls are not accessible from MS UI Automation. However, if AutomationElement.FromPoint() in UIA Verify can get a control, UIAutomationSpy should generate the code the UIAutomation module will use.